# <u> tag underline color not overridden by <a> color in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following line displays with a black underline in IE, but a blue one in other browsers:

```css
body {
  color: black;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #2883DE;
}
```

```html
<u>
  <a href="link">TITLE</a>
</u>
```

How can I get it to render blue in all browsers?

Comment: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: an anchor comes styled underline... Why use the `u` tag?

Comment: I get a blue underline on IE 8.

Comment: Just a guess/hunch but I'm guessing it depends on the user's settings or something, but since you are underlining the anchor tag, the underline is lining up just perfectly over top the default blue underline on (some) people's machine.

Comment: Yeah, I've been pouring over the code with the F12 developer tools in IE and cannot figure out why this is rendering black. I think the best bet is to just take out the <u> tags altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How do I get it to render blue in all browsers?

A: It is a very simple fix. You add css for  and color: blue

```
u{
color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffwvffmy/

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I can't seem to reproduce this error. You're right this should work, but for some reason on mine it just doesn't. My IE must be messed up.